# WiX XSLT transform messing up my formatting

Tags: xml, xslt, wix, transform, heat

I'm trying to use a transform to add an attribute to a Component description.  It is adding the attribute properly but messes up my XML formatting.

My goal is to add the attribute 'Permanent="yes" ' to the Component.

The XSLT is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
    xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">

    <xsl:template match="wix:Component">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
            <xsl:attribute name="Permanent">
                <xsl:text>yes</xsl:text>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="* | text()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@* | text()">
        <xsl:copy />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The .wxl file before transform looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="SystemFolder">
            <Component Id="tdbgpp7.dll" Guid="{FA172CDA-D111-49BD-940F-F72EB8AC90DA}">
                <File Id="tdbgpp7.dll" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.OC2.WinSys32)\tdbgpp7.dll" />
            </Component>
        </DirectoryRef>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

and after the transform looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="SystemFolder">
            <Component Id="tdbgpp7.dll" Guid="{415E5416-AFE3-4658-8D74-489554345219}" Permanent="yes"><File Id="tdbgpp7.dll" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.OC2.WinSys32)\tdbgpp7.dll" /></Component>
        </DirectoryRef>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

As you can see it is adding my attribute as expected but it loses some of the formatting.  The code still works but loses readability.  I know I must be missing something simple but so far it eludes me.  I'm a noob to this transform stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because in your template that matches `wix:Component` you do an `<xsl:apply-templates select="*" />`. This means you're only applying templates to elements so the text nodes (insignificant whitespace) inside of `wix:Component` are being stripped.

I would suggest an [identity transform](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#copying) and applying templates to `node()` in the `wix:Component` template...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
  xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="wix:Component">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
      <xsl:attribute name="Permanent">
        <xsl:text>yes</xsl:text>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly.  Exactly what I needed.

Comment: @gagidlof - you're very welcome. Please accept this answer by clicking the check mark (✅) next to it. Thanks!